# Continuity of a function on the union of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ and $B$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:A\cup B \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $f_{|A}$ and $f_{|B}$ are both continuous (Here, $f_{|A}$ means ''the restriction of $f$ to $A$'', respectively $f_{|B}$), and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Is there a sufficient and necessary condition on $A$ and $B$ which made of $f$ a continuous function on $A\cup B$?

My attemps: It is easy to prove that if $A$ and $B$ are both open (or closed), then $f$ is continuous on $A\cup B$. In the proof of this fact, I did't use that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. What I've used was the characterization of continuous functions by preimages of open sets, but I think that this condition is not a neccesary condition. Indeed, I don't know if there is a neccesary condition because the original exercise only asks "When is $f$ continuous on $A\cup B$?''

I took this problem from Section 2.3 of the book *Advanced Calculus* by R. Buck and E. Buck, 3rd. Edition (page 89).

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: $f^{-1}(U)=(f|_A)^{-1}(U) \cup  (f|_B)^{-1}(U) $

Comment: Yes, I've use it to show that "if $A$ and $B$ open (or closed), then $f$ is continuous on $A\cup B$". What I'm asking is for a neccesary condition, i.e., if $f$ is continuous on $A\cup B$, and provided that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, what can we say about $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should be interpreted as follows:

Let $A, B \subset \mathbb R^n$ be disjoint. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $A, B$ such that for **each** $f : A\cup B \to \mathbb{R}^m$ the continuity of $f_{|A}$ and $f_{|B}$ implies the continuity of $f$.

Without any condition on $A, B$ this may of course be true for **some** $f$. The desired condition is that $A, B$ are *separated* which means that $\overline A \cap B = A \cap \overline B = \emptyset$.

1. Let $A,B$ be not separated. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $A \cap \overline B \ne \emptyset$. Choose two distinct points $a, b  \in \mathbb R^m$ and define $f(x) = a$ for $x \in A$ and $f(x) = b$ for $x \in B$. Then $f_{|A}$ and $f_{|B}$ are continuous, but $f$ is  not. In fact, since $A \cap \overline B \ne \emptyset$, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $B$ converging to some $\xi \in A$. Then $f(x_n) = b$ does not converge to $f(\xi) = a$.
2. Let $A,B$ be separated. Consider a point $\xi \in  A \cup B$ and a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A \cup B$ converging to $\xi$.
   Case 1. Only finitely many $x_n$ lie in $A$. Then almost all $x_n$ lie in $B$ and we conclude $\xi \in \overline B$. But $A \cap \overline B = \emptyset$, thus $\xi \notin A$ and we conclude $\xi  \in B$. Thus $f(x_n) \to f(\xi)$ since $ \mid_Bf$ is continuous.
   Case 2. Infinitely many $x_n$ lie in $A$. Then $\xi \in \overline A$ and as in case 1 we can conclude that $\xi \in A$. It is impossible that also infinitely many $x_n$ lie in $B$ because that would imply $\xi \in B$ (same argument). Hence almost all $x_n$ lie in $A$ and  $f(x_n) \to f(\xi)$ since $ \mid_Af$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a condition on $A$ and $B$ which is necessary and sufficient for continuity of $f$ **whenever** its restrictions on $A$ and $B$ are continuous, then the answer is $A$ and $B$ are both open: Let $f=0$ on $A$ and $2$ on $B$. Then its restrictions are continuous. If $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(-1,1)$ has to be open which means $A$ has to be open in $A \cup B$. Similarly, $B$ has to be open in $A\cup B$.

Comment: No. Take $n = m = 1$ and $A = [0,1), B= (1,2]$. These sets are neither open nor closed. But each function having continuous restrictions to $A, B$ is continuous.

Comment: Since the domain of $f$ is $A \cup B$  I was talking about openness in $A \cup B$, not openness in $\mathbb R^{n}$. @PaulFrost

Comment: I see. You clarified this in your answer.